# Blank input Parameters in a WHERE condition of a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a report with 10 input parameters wherein only two are obligatory, the rest are optional. The problem is, as far as I know, if you use an input parameter that is blank in a WHERE condition of a SELECT statement no records will be selected from a table, so how to fix that ?

lets try something simple:

```
SELECT * FROM contrat WHERE article = 'sumsung' AND price = null
```

the user entered an article and did not enter a price
so the query will return nothing because price is null even when we have a contract with a sumsung article

Comment: The question is a tad unclear, at least to me. Can you share the query and sample parameters?

Comment: check the question again please i added more details.

Comment: you have to build the query after checking the user input, like if($article != "") $sql = $sql." your sql related to article", use prepared statement to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by blank you mean `null` or an empty string, you must construct for each of the optional parameters a condition like:

```
column_name = :optional_param OR :optional_param IS NULL
```

or:

```
column_name = :optional_param OR :optional_param = ''
```

So, your `WHERE` clause should look like:

```
WHERE <conditions for the non null parameters>
  AND (column_name1 = :optional_param1 OR :optional_param1 IS NULL) 
  AND (column_name2 = :optional_param2 OR :optional_param2 IS NULL)
  AND .......
```